How to get push notifications in Flutter when there is a new entry from API?
Recently I've been working on a Flutter app that lists orders from API. How can I get push notifications from the app when there is a new order entry from the API? A refresh interval of 1-5 minutes would be relevant. And is it possible to make it locally (not using Firebase etc)?
